# Why do Superconductors make Magnetic Fields Bend Away

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

When superconductors reach their "threshold temperature" their electrical resistance turns 0. This makes the magnetic field lines not pass through the superconductor but instead bend itself around it and is called the [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect). Why is this so?

Comment: I corrected *what* is called the Meissner effect here (you seemed to say that superconductivity is called that). What about the explanation in e.g. the Wiki article doesn't satisfy you? Do you want to see the technical (mathy) explanation?

Comment: I believe that it's conceptually possible to have a "perfect conductor" that conducts, but doesn't exhibit the Meissner effect. A superconductor is considered to have two different properties, the 0 resistance, and the Meissner effect. It also refers to the *expulsion* of the field.

Comment: Yes, if you could offer a more mathematical explanation, that would be great. Also, the wiki definition does explain it, but doesn;t explain why the reason works.